# How can I parse a string up to a specific character, and nothing after that character

Tags: batch-file

So I am using a batch script to send me notifications when certain actions are completing on my home server. The problem is one set of actions has a name format I can't modify, but I want the name to come through clean without additional content.

For example, what I want to see is: This File Is Done Processing

What I am seeing is: This File Is Done Processing [additional file info]

The batch variable I am using to extract the file name is: SET PName=%*

So my question is can is there a way to modify that variable for parsing to exclude the first [ in the string and everything after it?

Comment: Yes. You can use a `FOR /F` command and the `DELIMS` option to split apart the variable.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `FOR /?` to read the help for the `FOR` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
set "var=This File Is Done Processing [additional file info]"
set "var=%var:[=&rem %"
set var=%var%
```

it replaces the things after `[` with `&rem` which later is processed as  command

or with `for /f`:

```
set "var=This File Is Done Processing [additional file info]"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[" %%# in ("%var%") do (
   set "var=%%#"
)
echo %var%
```

Comment: Thank you, switched "var" out with "PName" and that did it.

Comment: Need a space after the rem other wise you get this error. `'remadditional' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 2):

One other option that builds off of @npocmaka's &REM trick with the `SET` command.

```
set "pname=This File Is Done Processing [additional] [file]"
(set "pname=%pname:[=" & set /p "=%" )<nul >nul
```

It could also be done this way but creates an extra variable named as a period.

```
set "pname=This File Is Done Processing [additional] [file]"
set "pname=%pname:[=" & set ".=%"
```

The idea behind both of these is to just have one less line of code.